# How do I serve, and refer to, static resources such as images in my web application?

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatable to show extra information when click on the plus sign. The event of clicking it's working but the + - is not showing on the row. I already included in my folder as image and called it using :

```
<style>
td.details-control {
    background: url('~/wwwroot/Images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
          cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('~/wwwroot/Images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: This is not a DataTables question. It's a question about whatever server you are using to serve your static resources.

Comment: I figure out the solution <style>
    td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    tr.shown td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    }
</style>

Comment: That is not a solution. It is a work-around. But that may be OK for your specific situation.